# How can I use the gmail API with discord.py to send the 10 most recent unread emails as individual messages in a chat every minute?

Tags: python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api, discord.py

```
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import base64
import time
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Gmail API
    repeat = 0
    while repeat <= 10:
        labelName = "READ-BY-SCRIPT"
        LABEL_ID = 'Label_8507504117657095973'
        results = service.users().messages().list(
            userId='me', q="-label:"+labelName, maxResults=1).execute()
        messages = results.get('messages', [])
        body = []
        if not messages:
            repeat += 10
            time.sleep(60)
        else:
            for message in messages:
                msg = service.users().messages().get(
                    userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
                labels = msg['labelIds']
                if "INBOX" in labels:
                    body.append(msg['payload']['parts'])
                    body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(
                        body[0][0]['body']['data'])
                    body = str(body)
                    if 'b"\\r\\nHi MOHAMMAD,\\r\\n' or "b'\\r\\nHi MOHAMMAD,\\r\\n" in body:
                        if 'posted a new assignment in IX K  \\r\\n<https://classroom.google.com/c/MTEyNDMxODgyMTE0>.' in body:
                            body = body.replace(
                                "\\r\\nIf you don\\'t want to receive emails from Classroom, you can unsubscribe  \\r\\n<https://classroom.google.com/s>.\\r\\n\\r\\nGoogle LLC\\r\\n1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy\\r\\nMountain View, CA 94043 USA\\r\\n'", "")
                            body = body.replace("b\"", "").replace("b'", "").replace('"', '').replace("   ", ' ').replace(
                                "  ", ' ').replace(" \\n<https://classroom.google.com/c/MTEyNDMxODgyMTE0>", "").replace("\\n", "\\n\\n")
                            body = body.replace("\\r\\n\\nHi MOHAMMAD,\\r\\n\\n", "").replace(" \\r\\n\\n<https://classroom.google.com/c/MTEyNDMxODgyMTE0>.\\r\\n", "").replace(
                                "\\r\\n\\nIf you don't want to receive emails from Classroom, you can unsubscribe \\r\\n\\n<https://classroom.google.com/s>.\\r\\n\\n\\r\\n\\nGoogle LLC\\r\\n\\n1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy\\r\\n\\nMountain View, CA 94043 USA\\r\\n\\n", "")
                            body = body.replace("\\r", "\r").replace(
                                "\\n", "\n").replace("\n\n", "\n").replace("\\\\", "\\")
                            body = body.replace("\\xe2", "").replace(
                                "\\x80", "").replace("\\x99", "").replace("\\x98", "")
                            body = body.replace(
                                "\\r\\nIf you don\\'t want to receive emails from Classroom, you can unsubscribe  \\r\\n<https://classroom.google.com/s>.\\r\\n\\r\\nGoogle LLC\\r\\n1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy\\r\\nMountain View, CA 94043 USA\\r\\n'", "")
                            body = body.replace("\\'", "")
                            body = body.replace(
                                "\\r\\nIf you don\\'t want to receive emails from Classroom, you can unsubscribe", "")
                            body = body.replace(
                                "If you dont want to receive emails from Classroom, you can unsubscribe\n <https://classroom.google.com/s>.\nGoogle LLC\n1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy\nMountain View, CA 94043 USA\n", "")

                            TEACHER_NAME = body.split("posted", 1)[0]
                            body = body.replace(TEACHER_NAME, "")
                            LINK = str(body.split("\r\nOPEN \r\n<", 1)[1])
                            LINK = LINK[:-1]
                            body = body.replace(LINK, "").replace("<", "").replace(">", "").replace(
                                'posted a new assignment in IX K\n\r\n', "").replace("\r\nOPEN \r\n", "")
                            if 'Due: ' in body:
                                body = body.replace("\n", "          ", 1)
                                DATE = body.split('          ')[0]
                                body = body.split('          ')[1]
                            else:
                                body = body
                                DATE = 'No Due Date Provided'
                            print(TEACHER_NAME)
                            print("")
                            print(LINK)
                            print("")
                            print(DATE)
                            print("")
                            print(body)
                            service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=message['id'], body={
                                'addLabelIds': ['Label_8507504117657095973']}).execute()
                            repeat += 1
                        else:
                            service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=message['id'], body={
                                'addLabelIds': [LABEL_ID]}).execute()
                            pass
                    else:
                        service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=message['id'], body={
                            'addLabelIds': [LABEL_ID]}).execute()
                        pass
                else:
                    service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=message['id'], body={
                        'addLabelIds': ['Label_8507504117657095973']}).execute()
                    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my code. It gets the most recent email that does not have a label "read by script" and checks if it follows the template of a google classroom and then gets data (Teacher's name [TEACHER_NAME]; Link to the assignment [LINK]; the due date of the assignment [DATE]; and the details of the assignment [body]) the from it and prints said data and then repeats 9 more times. How can I get this code to, using discord.py, print all of these as a message in a discord chat.

Answer (score 0):

First you should rewrite your function so that it actually returns the contents from your gmail, preferably in blocks of text no bigger than 2000 chars (the limit in discord descriptions/messages).

You can then use [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/ext/tasks/index.html) to do so periodically do something, like calling your `main` function

```py
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
...

def main():
    ...

class Gmail(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.logger.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.logger.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(minutes=10)
    async def logger(self):
        emails = main()
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(your log channel ID (int))
        for email in emails:
            await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=email))

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Gmail(bot))
...
```

First you will want to create a new file, name it `gmail.py`, in which you can use the example code above.

Then put it in a folder called `cogs`. Go to your main file, I assume `bot.py`, and call `bot.load_extension('cogs.gmail')` to load the cog.

Since we start the task in `Gmail.__init__` you don't have to do anything else, apart from importing your main function to `gmail.py` or just copying it over.

Comment: what do I add at the end after bot.add_cog(Gmail(bot))

Comment: If you put this in a separate file, which is what I recommend, nothing.

Comment: how do I link this file to another file in which I run the bot?

Comment: Check out [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/ext/commands/cogs.html#ext-commands-cogs) and [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension) sarticle

Comment: i still don't understand what to write in my bot.py to run that code. I cant find it in those links. My english isn't that good.

Comment: it says that bot is not defined.

```import discord
client = discord.Client()

TOKEN = "Mytoken"

bot.load_extension('cogs.gmail')

client.run(TOKEN)```

Comment: Yeah that is something different, you should be able to figure that one out yourself. Check out [a basic bot](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_bot.py)

Comment: I pasted the wrong code and the wrong explanation. Does the same method still work with the updated code (check the original question, i edited it)